# PHP error with multiple levels of key-value JSON pairs

Tags: c#, php, mysql, json

I am using multiple levels of JSON data coming into php from a C# application, as in:

```
public class User_Group
{
    public int ID_UserGroup { get; set; }
    public string Name_UserGroup { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
public class User_Role
{
    public int ID_User { get; set; }
    public string Role_User { get; set; }
    public string User_Role_Description { get; set; }
    public List<User_Group> UserGroup { get; set; }
}

public class Stand_Orte
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
    public List<Modul> modul { get; set; }
}

public class Modul
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Seriennummer { get; set; }
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
    public string StandortID { get; set; }
    public List<Mess_Kanal> MessKanal { get; set; }
}

public class Mess_Kanal
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ModulID { get; set; }
    public List<LogMess_Daten> LogMessDaten { get; set; }
}

public class LogMess_Daten
{
    public string KanalID { get; set; }
    public string Zeitstempel { get; set; }

}


public class RootObject
{
    public int ID_Project { get; set; }
    public string Name_Project { get; set; }
    public int Receiver_ID { get; set; }
    public string Receiver_Name { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User_Role UserRole { get; set; }
    public Stand_Orte Standorte { get; set; }
}
```

I have an issue with accessing the 3rd level data elements.
For Eg., I am able to get the values uptil Project-> Stand_Orte-> Modul. but after that Project-> Stand_Orte-> Modul-> MessKanal Throws an error in PHP as " Trying to get property of non-object  ".
I tried the following:

> 1. $phpArray['project']->Standorte[0]->modul[0]->MessKanal[0]->ID
> 2. $messkanals=$phpArray->Standorte->modul->MessKanal;

And then used a "foreach ($messkanals as $messkanal)" to insert MessKanal data into MYSQL.
it gives me the following errors respectively.

> 1. Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
> 2. Trying to get property of non-object

does anyone have any idea?

Thanks,
Revathy

Comment: Are you using json_decode to decode your json?

if you are, are you specifying the second parameter 'assoc'

i.e. json_decode($json,true)

assoc
When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: i tried using assoc and without assoc. using assoc, Im not able to access the first level- project, here. without assoc, im unable to access 3rd level- MessKanal, here.